# React Formik insert a formik form into parent formik form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

currently, I have the parent component and children component `Dialog` with different `formik` form, the brief structure which is like this

```
<Formik initialValues={...} onSubmit={...}>
  //some form fields here
  <Button type="submit" />
  <Button onClick={()=>{setDialogOpen(true)}}/>
  <Dialog Open={dialogOpen}>
</Formik>

<Dialog>
  <Formik initialValues={...} onSubmit={...}>
    //some form fields here
    <Button type="submit" />
  </Formik>
</Dialog>
```

For some reason I can't take `Dialog` out of the parent `formik`, the issue is when I click the children's submit button, the parents' `formik` form will also be triggered, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the submit button event is bubbling to the top formik.
If you use the formik hook `useFormik` you can then have two separate forms and call submit on each button:

```
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
const [parentForm] = useFormik();
const [dialogForm] = useFormik();

<Formik initialValues={...} onSubmit={...} form={parentForm}>
  //some form fields here
  <Button onClick={() => parentForm.submit()} />
  <Button onClick={()=>{setDialogOpen(true)}}/>
  <Dialog Open={dialogOpen}>
</Formik>

<Dialog>
  <Formik initialValues={...} onSubmit={...} form={dialogForm}>
    //some form fields here
    <Button onClick={() => dialogForm.submit()} />
  </Formik>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The Formik docs suggest you need to pass something into the `userFormik()` call https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik#example